# Fixed Div Not Positioning on Left Correctly When Using Transform Rotate

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at **[THIS DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5mgork9a/)**  and let me know why the `left:0px;` is not working when I use `-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);`

Thanks

```css
#tab{
    position:fixed;
    width:120px;
    height:15px;
    left:-0px;
    background:green;
    top:300px;
    padding:15px;
    text-align: center;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">Draw</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reposition after the transform. This can be done with transform-origin:
[Mozilla documentation on transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)
Also check out this post, which explains how a transform takes place:
[Sitepoint article, scroll to The transform-origin Property](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-primer-on-css3-transforms/)

```css
#tab{
    position:fixed;
    width:120px;
    height:15px;
    left:-0px;
    background:green;
    top:300px;
    padding:15px;
    text-align: center;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top; /* this does the trick */
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">Draw</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathijs Rutgers  but this is also changing the top postion of the `#tab`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Where would you expect the #tab to come?